# Principled python script for selected object

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

I want to ask a solution for blender scipt for principled. I have imported about 50 characters in FBX format, problem is that every one of them have about 10-15 materials with principled but they are wrong. I never scripted in python so Im in the dark right now. What I want to do I want create script for selected material that use Principled to set:

Specular and 
Metallic

to 0.0

and disconnect(clear)

Alpha and
Normal

I found here this script and I try to recreate that but I'm afraid im too green to do that right. If anyone will be able to help it would be great!

```
import bpy

# I separated the creation of nodes to a function so it's easier 
# to edit later if needed
def create_nodes(mat): 
    mat.use_nodes = True
    nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
    for every_node in nodes: # this removes all existing nodes
        nodes.remove(every_node)

    # creating Principled node and moving it:
    node = nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled')
    node.location = (-190,100)

    # creating Output node and moving it:
    output_node = nodes.new('ShaderNodeOutputMaterial')
    output_node.location = (40,100)

    # creating the link between the two nodes:
    links = mat.node_tree.links
    link = links.new(node.outputs[0], output_node.inputs[0])

# this saves the currently active object so it can be restored later
active = bpy.context.object 

# let's loop through all selected objects
for every_object in bpy.context.selected_objects: 
    # I only want to work with objects capable of having a material
    if every_object.type in {'MESH','CURVE', 'SURFACE','META', 'FONT'}: 
        if every_object.name not in bpy.data.materials:
        # if there is no material named after the object yet let's make one
            mat = bpy.data.materials.new(every_object.name)
            # and let's create the nodes for it
            create_nodes(mat)
        else:
            # if the material already exists let's just use it
            mat = bpy.data.materials.get(every_object.name)
        if len(every_object.material_slots) == 0: # if there are no material slots
            # let's make the current object active and create a material slot
            bpy.context.scene.objects.active = every_object
            bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add() 
            # let's leave the active object as it was
            bpy.context.scene.objects.active = active

        # The only thing left now is to assign the material to 
        # all material slots. We probably do not want to loose the info
        # about how the object is divided into separate materials
        for every_slot in every_object.material_slots:
            every_slot.material = mat
```

Comment: I will post a solution in about an hour.

Comment: I will appreciate your help with this situation, I made mistake in main post, I meant for selected obj, not material. Sorry for mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code iterates through all selected objects and their respective materials found in the material slots. If a *Principled BSDF* node is found in the material, the *Specular* and *Metallic* properties are set to zero and links to *Alpha* and *Normal* are removed.

Be aware that every material will be fixed that is present in the selected objects' material slots. If that includes a material that is also assigned to an unselected object, that change will affect the unselected object as well.

```
import bpy


def remove_links(socket: bpy.types.NodeSocket, node_tree: bpy.types.NodeTree):
    """Remove all links from or to the given socket"""
    for link in socket.links:
        node_tree.links.remove(link)


def fix_node(node: bpy.types.Node, node_tree: bpy.types.NodeTree):
    """Adjust the properties if the node is a Principled BSDF"""
    if node.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED':
        node.inputs['Specular'].default_value = 0.0
        node.inputs['Metallic'].default_value = 0.0
        remove_links(node.inputs['Alpha'], node_tree)
        remove_links(node.inputs['Normal'], node_tree)


def fix_material(material: bpy.types.Material):
    """Fix the nodes of the given material"""
    for node in material.node_tree.nodes:
        fix_node(node, material.node_tree)


def fix_selected():
    """Fix the materials of the selected objects"""
    for object in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        for material_slot in object.material_slots:
            fix_material(material_slot.material)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fix_selected()
```